# AttributeError: object has no attribute 'listbox'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, listbox

In this simple script an item selected in `listbox` on `Page1` is saved and printed from a `Page2`.  The value in `listbox` is saved in `app_data`.  The code runs, but no value is recorded in `app_data` (the value printed is blank).  The following exception occurs:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1536, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)   File "filepath/file.py", line 35, in <lambda>
    button1 = ttk.Button(self,text="Next Page",command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Page2)
                         or self.controller.app_data["listbox"]
                         .set(self.listbox.get(self.listbox.curselection())))
AttributeError: 'Page1' object has no attribute 'listbox'
```

From what I can tell the controller is unable to recognize the listbox.  I looked into a possible resolution using `super()` as shown in [Understanding Python super() with init() methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576169/understanding-python-super-with-init-methods) but have not had success.

**Question:**
What will enable listbox values to correctly save to `app_data`?

```
button1 = ttk.Button(self,text="Next Page"
                     ,command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Page2)
                     or self.controller.app_data["listbox"]
                     .set(self.listbox.get(self.listbox.curselection()))
```

**Full Code:**

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class MyApp(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)

        # App data in controller
        self.app_data = {"listbox":    StringVar()}

        container = ttk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        self.frames = {}

        for F in (Page1, Page2):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky = NSEW)
        self.show_frame(Page1)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class Page1(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        listbox = Listbox(self,exportselection=0)
        listbox.grid()
        for item in [0,1,2,3,4,5]:
            listbox.insert(END, item)

        button1 = ttk.Button(self,text="Next Page"
                             ,command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Page2)
                             or self.controller.app_data["listbox"]
                             .set(self.listbox.get(self.listbox.curselection())))
        button1.grid()

class Page2(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        ttk.Label(self, text='Next Page').grid(padx=(20,20), pady=(20,20))
        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text='Select Page',
                             command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Page1))
        button1.grid()
        button2 = ttk.Button(self, text='print value', command=self.print_value)
        button2.grid()
    def print_value(self):
        value = self.controller.app_data["listbox"].get()
        print ('The value stored in StartPage some_entry = ' + str(value))

app = MyApp()
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is simple: in `button1` definition you use some methods of `self.listbox`, but when you defined your listbox, you haven't defined it as an attribute of `Page1`: `listbox = Listbox(self,exportselection=0)` (no `self.` in front of it). That's why you get the error `AttributeError: 'Page1' object has no attribute 'listbox'`.

There are two ways to avoid this:

- If you need to use the listbox somewhere outside the `__init__` method of `Page1`, make it an attribute: `self.listbox = Listbox(self,exportselection=0)` and replace all the `listbox` by `self.listbox`.
- If you don't need it anywhere else, just change the `self.listbox` in `listbox` in the `button1` definition:

  ```
  button1 = ttk.Button(self,text="Next Page"
                       ,command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Page2)
                       or self.controller.app_data["listbox"]
                       .set(listbox.get(listbox.curselection())))
  ```